# I can't get process to correctly open up the directory in Windows due to forward slashes

Tags: python, process, os.path

I need to use the subprocess.Popen to open an explorer window (in Windows only) with a path but the path I'm using has forward slashes and this doesn't work, only opens a generalized PC explorer window.  If I manually replace those with backslashes it works just fine, but I need this to happen for a variable path.

I've tried to use os.path.dirname in an effort to "normalize" the path, but this doesn't work either.  IOW, this code only gives me the generalized PC explorer window:

```
myRoot = "D:/SomePath/Somefile"
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select, myRoot')
```

or even:

```
myRoot = "D:/SomePath/Somefile"
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select, os.path.abspath(myRoot)')
```

but this works:

```
myRoot = "D:\SomePath\Somefile"
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select, myRoot')
```

I've also tried replacing manually those forward slash strings but I can't get it no matter how many ways I've tried (so obviously doing something wrong).  Any clues?  (I ONLY need this to work in Windows, and there is no way I can get the forward slashes not to come in because I'm reading from a file created with an outside program).

I appreciate the help folks are trying to provide -- let me try and clarify this, though.  The line of the path comes in from an outside file I cannot control.  So it ALWAYS looks like the example with the forward slashes, which does NOT work with opening the explorer subprocess no matter how I try it (including the examples given below).

If I just manually supply the path with backslashes, however, it does work.  So what I need is something that will convert the forward slashed path to a backslashed one.  And so far nothing suggested here works.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've also tried replacing manually those forward slash strings but I can't get it no matter how many ways I've tried"? In your third example, with back slashes, you say that it works.

Comment: 2nd method works

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(rf'explorer /select, {os.path.abspath(myRoot)}')`

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(["explorer", "/select", myRoot.replace("/", "\\")])`.

Comment: No, none of those replacements work.  The second one (with the .replace) gets me to My Documents directory (weird because the path is on the D: drive so no C: in there at all).  And what I say by "no replacements work" I mean no computed replacements work.  I can manually write the path with the right slashes but no matter what I try to replace those slashes programmatically it does not work -- it will not replace them nor return the right path.

Comment: OKAY!!!!  SUCCESS -- thank you SmartManoj!  THAT does work (not quite sure how to say this is the answer when it's kind of buried here, but using the curly braces was the key, I think).  Maybe you could post it as an answer I could then upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pretty sure this is nothing to do with the "forward slashes", but caused by several other confusions about how Python works and how command arguments get from one process to another.

```
myRoot = "D:/SomePath/Somefile"
subprocess.Popen(rf'explorer /select, {os.path.abspath(myRoot)}')
```

works, because the Python variable has been expanded into the string passed to `Popen`, this is equivalent to:

```
cmdline = rf'explorer /select, {os.path.abspath(myRoot)}'
subprocess.Popen(cmdline)
```

which is also equivalent to:

```
cmdline = 'explorer /select, {root}'.format(
    root=os.path.abspath(myRoot))
subprocess.Popen(cmdline)
```

the `f` prefix to the string is known as a "[f-string](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/)" (short for [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings))

if you `print(cmdline)` you'll see it's been expanded to:
`"explorer /select, D:/SomePath/Somefile"` and hence the path can get to the MS Explorer process.

when you were running `Popen(r'explorer /select, myRoot')` the `myRoot` variable wasn't being expanded and hence Explorer was only seeing the text `"myRoot"` which it was likely ignoring.

The recommended alternative would be to pass a `list` to `Popen`, which each element being a seperate command line argument.  For example:

```
Popen(['explorer', '/select', myRoot])
```

which sort of looks like you were trying to do, but not getting right.

The other issue you seemed to be having trouble is with "escape sequences" and strings.  When you're writing code, a backslash is written as `'\\'` but this is just a single character after it's been parsed.  For example, with:

```
myRoot = "D:\\SomePath\\Somefile"
print(myRoot)
```

will just print out: `D:\SomePath\Somefile`.  This variable should also work fine with the above `Popen` call.

The `r` prefix disables this escape handling, and was designed for "regular expressions" (or "regexp"s, see the [`re` Python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)).  There are lots of articles about this, hope some of what I've written contains some keyworkds that Google understands.

Comment: Thanks, that does explain a lot (and got me to where I wanted to go).  I upvoted but it says with less than 15 rep it won't show/count, but I do have 15 rep so a bit clueless on why that didn't work).

Answer (score 1):

Use the pathlib module.

```
from pathlib import Path
myRoot = Path("D:/path/to/wherever")
```

This works with `subprocess` as well